# How to animate a loader gif progressing according to percentage of a video/ image loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to animate a loading circle 1 complete round progressing with the loading of image . It should start the round when loading starts & complete one round when the loading is done.

How can I do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is not possible - the browser doesn't return any live information about the loading progress of a HTML image that you could use to power an animation.

All it *does* return is the `load` event that you can attach to an image. That will fire when an image is completely loaded.

Comment: actually I saw this sometime ago on  a flash website, and wanted to replicate with html..

Comment: @Raj as said, I don't think it's possible with HTML. You simply don't get the data necessary to do this